# Method 'requestAuthorization:' not defined in Plugin 'PhotoLibrary' ionic 4

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, plugins, ionic4

I have add Photo Library Plugin, Follow the instruction on ionic doc [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/photo-library)

I add Plugin using `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-photo-library --variable PHOTO_LIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION="To choose photos" --save` command

After i add platform using `ionic cordova platform add ios` command

When i get all photo from library i get below error

> ERROR: Method 'requestAuthorization:' not defined in Plugin
>   'PhotoLibrary'

i define that method on button click like below

```
async getAllPhotos() {
    this.photoLibrary.requestAuthorization().then(() => {
        this.photoLibrary.getLibrary().subscribe({
            next: library => {
                library.forEach(function(libraryItem) {
                    console.log(libraryItem.id);          // ID of the photo
                    console.log(libraryItem.photoURL);    // Cross-platform access to photo
                    console.log(libraryItem.thumbnailURL); // Cross-platform access to thumbnail
                    console.log(libraryItem.fileName);
                    console.log(libraryItem.width);
                    console.log(libraryItem.height);
                    console.log(libraryItem.creationDate);
                    console.log(libraryItem.latitude);
                    console.log(libraryItem.longitude);
                    console.log(libraryItem.albumIds);    // array of ids of appropriate AlbumItem, only of includeAlbumsData was used
                });
            },
            error: err => { console.log('could not get photos'); },
            complete: () => { console.log('done getting photos'); }
        });
    }).catch(err => console.log('permissions weren\'t granted'));
}
```

Here i add `ionic info`

Ionic:

```
   ionic (Ionic CLI)             : 4.10.2 (/Users/atologistimac2/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.1.2
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.13.7
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.2.4
   @angular/cli                  : 7.3.7
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.4.1
```

Cordova:

```
   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.1.4, ios 5.0.0
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.0.1, (and 18 other plugins)
```

System:

```
   ios-deploy : 1.9.4
   ios-sim    : 7.0.0
   NodeJS     : v10.15.1 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm        : 6.9.0
   OS         : macOS High Sierra
   Xcode      : Xcode 10.1 Build version 10B61
```

What am i doing wrong here?

if anyone have solution than please share it will be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is how i resolved it... its better to install the following plugins with correct versions and it will work perfectly.

cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-add-swift-support
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-photo-library

cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-add-swift-support@1.7.2
cordova plugin add https://github.com/nilebma/cordova-plugin-photo-library.git

and everything will work fine again. If you face any issue just delete these plugins from plugins folder manually and then install the plugins.

Comment: cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-add-swift-support;
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-photo-library;
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-add-swift-support@1.7.2;
cordova plugin add https://github.com/nilebma/cordova-plugin-photo-library.git;